# regex (javascript) word within random string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find a word in a random letters string.  So for example, find `"pass"` in the following string

```
asjh;ssdf2222fasdfpasslkjsdfk.^%£$fh
```

Need some regex help!

Comment: Have you made any attempts?

Comment: I made many attempts on my own using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ before asking

Comment: It's encouraged that you include any attempts you've made with your question, as it usually makes it easier for others to see your thought process and specific mistakes, which typically leads to clearer and fuller explanations/answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know exactly what you are looking for, a regex is overkill.

```
if( str.indexOf("pass") > -1) { alert("Pass!"); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
'asjh;ssdf2222fasdfpasslkjsdfk.^%£$fh'.match(/pass/);
```

Comment: However if you just need to find substring in a string, use @Kolink method - there is no need to use regex for that.